# Double values lose precision in tcl after string\list operations

Tags: tcl

While working with tcl, I discover such a behavior: when I looping over double variable it lose its precision.

```
set dbl  [expr { double(13.0/7.0) }]
set dbl2 [expr { double(13.0/7.0) }]
foreach a $dbl {
}
if { $dbl == $dbl2 } {
    puts "\$dbl == \$dbl2"
} else {
    puts "\$dbl != \$dbl2" ;# they will be not equal
}
```

As I soon find out, when you use operations that work with strings or lists (e.g. llength, lindex, string first, rsub, foreach, etc.) the double representation of variable will be replaced with string representation which will be created or was created earlier, based on `$tcl_precision` value. Furthermore, every copy of this double variable that was created with `set` command, also will be spoiled.

Is there a way not to lose precision after such operations in tcl8.4 and without forcing `tcl_precision` to some fixed value?

P.S. `set tcl_precision 0` will work only in tcl8.5 or above versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Tcl 8.5 onwards, your code should Just Work. Considerable effort was put into 8.5 to make the default conversion of `double`s to strings (and hence to other types) not lose information. It also tries to use the minimum number of digits to do this on the grounds that this minimises the amount of surprise presented to people; yes, we had a real expert working on this.

For 8.4 and before, set `tcl_precision` to 17. That guarantees that no significant bits are lost, though the representation used may be considerably longer than minimal.